# Add cookie to the header in SoapUI using GROOVY script

Tags: cookies, groovy, automation, soapui

I am pretty new to GROOVY script. 
I trigger a request from soapUI, which basically does a login to the database and returns cookie as part of the header

[image]

I need a groovy script, which can take the value of the `cookie (EDEV)`[marked red in the above pic] and pass the value to all other request inside a TestSuite.

Currently I am using the below GROOVY script to achieve this, but unable to do it. Can someone help?

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport
def myCookieStore = HttpClientSupport.getHttpClient().getCookieStore()
def val = testRunner.testCase.testSteps['Login'].testRequest.response.getResponseHeaders()
def re = /(EDEV=.*,)/
def matcher = ( val =~ re )
def cookie = matcher[0][0]
def map=[:]
testRunner.testCase.testSteps['Login2'].testRequest.requestHeaders=map
def headers=testRunner.testCase.testSteps['Login2'].testRequest.requestHeaders
headers.put('Cookie', cookie)
testRunner.testCase.testSteps['Login2'].testRequest.requestHeaders=headers
```

Where `Login` is the testCase for login and `Login2` is the target testCase where the cookie value needs to be passed and added into the request header.

I have checked `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640173/how-do-i-get-a-cookie-from-a-soapui-response-using-a-groovy-test-step` this answer and did some edit on my script, but still I am unable to see the EDEV cookie in the next request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Cookie from a SoapUI response using a Groovy test step?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640173/how-do-i-get-a-cookie-from-a-soapui-response-using-a-groovy-test-step)

Comment: It doesn't work with the solution given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640173/how-do-i-get-a-cookie-from-a-soapui-response-using-a-groovy-test-step

Comment: At what point in your code are you reading the cookies from `myCookieStore`?!?!

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the headers of a request, and **not** the cookies.

To read your cookie:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport
def myCookieStore = HttpClientSupport.getHttpClient().getCookieStore()
def interestingCookie
myCookies.each {
    if(it.name == "EDEV")
        interestingCookie = it
}
```

There is only **one** cookie store in the session, so you will have to store your cookie somewhere, like in the properties:

```
testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("interestingCookie", interestingCookie)
```

At a later time, to set this cookie back

```
import org.apache.http.impl.Cookie.BasicClientCookie
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport
def myCookieStore = HttpClientSupport.getHttpClient().getCookieStore()
def interestingCookie = testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("interestingCookie")
def myNewCookie = new BasicClientCookie("EDEV", interestingCookie)
myCookieStore.addCookie(myNewCookie)
```

You can find [additional details](https://siking.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/soapui-cookie-management/) on my blog.

Comment: I totally misunderstood the question... you're right `:)`.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help either @SiKing.

Comment: @Saptarshi You will need to be more descriptive about what "it" is, and what *exactly* you are doing.